# WMP sounds are not working on other Computers

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, windows-media-player, wmplib

My project is to build a simple game and for now I only made the Main Menu `Form1` with 5 buttons.  The buttons have a `MouseClick` and `MouseEnter` on them, and I have a background music track using a WMP method (using WMPLib and axWMPLib).

My problem is when I'm taking the `bin/debug` putting it on a `rar` file and giving it to my friends, they say they don't hear the sound.  I made the project trough WMP version 11, so I asked them if their WMP version is 11 and they said yes.  I have no idea why I hear the sounds on my computer and they don't.

I tried to give them the folders:

- `bin\Release`
- `bin\Debug`
- `x86\Release`
- `x86\Debug`

but they still said that they can't hear any sound from all of them.

**EDIT**

All my sounds are in a folder called "Sounds". I found some details and found out that you need to embeding those WMP sounds to "Resources".

So how can I do that, and how I call them when `Form1` loads up. And no, this following code doesn't work:

```
BackGround.URL = Properties.Resources.Invincible;
```

It says I can't convert `System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream` to `String`.

Comment: Where are all of your music files stored?  Are they in the debug/release folders?

Comment: Please show us the code where you load the music files.

Comment: @user1703020, on StackOverflow the space below the question is for answers only, so if you have additional information that you want to add, you should edit your question to add it.  I've flagged the answer below for deletion, but I believe you should be able to delete it and add that information to the post yourself.

Comment: There could be dozens of reasons for this. Without code, its impossible to say for certainty. The two most obviously things that come to mind though is, either, you created the sound file and compressed it using an audio codec your friends don't have or you are referencing a library that is installed on your machine but not your friends machine. Post some code so we can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Sincerely I don't recommend you to use *WMP*, so give a look to the [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) class.
However I think the problem is that you don't give the correct location to your files. So what you can do is to locate your files in your application folder, get its location and create the location of the music files.

So try:

```
string musicName = Application.StartupPath + "music.mp3";
```

Or if you have a *Sounds* folder in the application path use:

```
string musicName = Application.StartupPath + "\\Sounds\\music.mp3";
```

Else if you insert your music file in the application resources this:

```
BackGround.URL = Properties.Resources.Invincible;
```

didn't work because `BackGround.URL` is of type string while `Properties.Resources.Invincible` is the music file stream.

I don't know if using *WMP* you can set the stream from where it can play the file. Although the `SoundPlayer` class I linked previously contains a property from where you can set the input stream. You can do it in this way:

```
SoundPlayer mySoundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
mySoundPlayer.Stream = Properties.Resources.Invincible;
mySoundPlayer.Load();
mySounPlayer.Play(); //plays the Properties.Resources.Invincible sound
```